# Is it possible to take a HFR (High Frame Rate) movie with RX10 II and Sony Camera Remote API beta SDK?

Tags: sony, sony-camera-api

I can't find the way to take a HFR (High Frame Rate) movie with RX10 II and Sony Camera Remote API beta SDK.

I have read official developer document.

Any idea on how I can take a High Frame Rate movie with 960[fps]?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is not possible using the Camera Remote SDK.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I hope it will be enabled ! m(_ _)m